# Good UPPER bounds for $\log(\sum_{i=1}^n p_ie^{z_i})-\sum_{i=1}^np_iz_i$ where $(p_i)_i$ is a probability vector

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities, approximation-theory, entropy, elementary-proofs

Let $x=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ be real vector and $(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ be a probability vector.

## Question

$\log(\sum_{i=1}^n p_ie^{z_i})-\sum_{i=1}^np_iz_i \le ???$

## Observation

This paper allows us to upper-bound things like $\Delta_f(z,p):=f(\sum_{i}z_i p_i) - \sum_i f(p_iz_i)$, thus providing a kind of reversed Jensen's inequality.

Indeed, it was shown that

> If $f$ is concave, $a:=\min_i z_i$ and $b := \max_i z_i$, then
>   $$
> \Delta_f(z,p) \le \max_{p,q \ge 0,\;p+q=1} pf(b)+qf(a) - f(pb+qa).
> $$

I could probably use this with $f=\log$ to bound $\Delta_{\log} (z,p)$.

Comment: What is $z_i{}$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Any obvious why reason this question got downvoted ? A comment from the downvoter would be particularly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It may look too simple as a research-level problem.

Comment: Ya, indeed. I thought I'd posted it on stackexchange. When I noticed it was on MO, it was already too late. But still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One answer - subgaussian variables generalize this property.

Let $\mu = \sum_i p_i z_i$, then the distribution is considered $\sigma^2$-subgaussian if for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$ \log\left(\sum_i p_i e^{\lambda(z_i - \mu)}\right) \leq \frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2} $$

i.e.

$$ \log\left(e^{-\lambda \mu} \sum_i p_i e^{\lambda z_i}\right) \leq \frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2} $$

i.e.

$$ \log\left(\sum_i p_i e^{\lambda z_i}\right) - \lambda \mu \leq \frac{\lambda^2 \sigma^2}{2} . $$

Your expression is the case $\lambda=1$.

In a sense this is not an answer, just a definition for when and how your inequality can be satisfied, but hopefully useful because we know ways to show variables are subgaussian:

1. Any random variable bounded in $[a,b]$ is $\left(\frac{b-a}{2}\right)^2$-subgaussian.
2. If $X$ is $\sigma^2$-subgaussian, then $cX$ is $c^2\sigma^2$-subgaussian.
3. If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2$ subgaussian, then $X+Y$ is $\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2$ subgaussian.

Comment: I should'have thought of that. Thanks!
Unfortunately the question got downvoted without any comment on why....

Comment: @dohmatob, agree, that is too bad (would have liked to see other approaches).